# How to call javascript function and pass some values from the android java code?

Tags: android, css, string, performance, android-intent

I want to pass some values to the JavaScript function from the android Java code. The Java script function is written in a HTML file. And I am loading the HTML file in a web-view.

My main target is to update the JavaScript variable values, that are using to draw pie,bar and line chart.

**Activity In android:**

```
    WebView mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webviewId);
    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/bar.html");
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

}
My question is how can i pass data from android Java to Java Script which is inside a HTML file

Comment: HI @Biplab, Is it that we need to call a javascript function only in onPageFinished. Is it possible to call a javascript function outside the WebViewClient().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmmmm...something like that...

```
 webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
        @Override  
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {  
            // Calling arg-less js method form android
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.yourJsFunc();"); 
            // I'm not sure with passing args, but you can try this...
            webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.yourJsFunc(\"arg0\", \"arg1\");"); 
        }  
    });
```

**NOTE:** In your case, if you implemented `MyWebViewClient`, you can override its `onPageFinishied()` and put this code in.

hope this helps..

Comment: Actually there are lot of html files are there in my project asset folder and inside lot of other JavaScript functions are there. How can i identify that from which html file i am going to access the script function?. I am somewhat confuse.

Comment: This will call the function from currently loaded html document in the web view at a time, and call would be successful if loaded page has the called function in it.

Comment: But before loading the html page is it possible to call a script function inside it?

Comment: OK finally i am able to do the communication between the java and java script. If any one need the sample code leave a comment here and your email-id.

Comment: HI @umair.ali, Is it that we need to call a javascript function only in onPageFinished. Is it possible to call a javascript function outside the WebViewClient().